# Get a System Service to run on day of month

Tags: timer

I have a project that creates a batch service to run jobs created in my main project. My issue is that with System.Timers.Timer it is not able to schedule past 28.4 days and the interval can not be variable. My batch service has around 9 operators on it and some are executed every few minutes, some daily, weekly, and monthly.

I have everything working except the monthly part and we are wanting to execute it on the 3rd Thursday of the month. I already know how to gt the third Thursday so that is not the issue. What is the problem is that I can't go past the 28.4 days and every month the interval will change. I have looked into System.Threading, but from what I can see is that I cannot use it with multiple jobs of different intervals.

Anyone have a solution or something for me to look into that might lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rethink your design to kick your timer off with shorter intervals (days, hours or even minutes) to check if it has reached some pre-stored date / time.

The problem with what you are suggesting above would be that if you restart the service or reboot the box, you will lose your timer.

So...  For the monthly run, set the timer up as 24 hours.  Store the next time it should run the job somewhere (database, file system, registry) and check this every time the timer event fires and run what needs to be run.

Comment: Yeah the rebooting/restart of the service is one of the issues I am trying to solve as well. thanks